# erb file syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, erb

```
a = Array.wrap(params[:a]).join(', ')
<% unless a.blank? %>
   <%= a%>,
   <% end %>
     b = Array.wrap(params[:where]).join(' AND ')
      <% unless params[:dedup] %>
     table_name
      WHERE <%= input_data_filter %>
       <% unless b.blank? %>
            AND <%= b %>
       <% end %>
       AND c - d <= <%= f%>

 <% else %>
```

This is the part of hql.erb file trying to write a query from it, can I transform the unless part of erb file into sql function

Comment: Well, that is a mess. You can do anything, though some things you shouldn't. This is one of such things. Move your queries to model (and I doubt you need raw SQL in your case, just use standard ActiveRecord methods). Move your data fetching to controllers. And leave views with only presentation logic.

Comment: I dont have the raw queries just some .erb files of them, I am stuck at how to define the 1st line and execute the unless in sql

Comment: Ah, so you are *building* queries with EBR? Well, that's another story! Well, you need to specify your question in a more general terms. Why do you need to convert ERB unless into SQL exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In an .erb template, everything that is not contained in <% %> is going to be evaluated as text.  Fixing up what you have, you may want to try something like:

```
<% a = Array.wrap(params[:a]).join(', ') %>
<% unless a.blank? %>
  <%= a%>
<% end %>

<% b = Array.wrap(params[:where]).join(' AND ') %>
<% unless params[:dedup] %>
  <%= table_name %>
  WHERE <%= input_data_filter %>
  <% unless b.blank? %>
    AND <%= b %>
  <% end %>
  AND c - d <= <%= f%>
<% else %>
```